# Regex for random string plus optional dash and number

Tags: regex

I would like to validate my string and would need help with regex. How do I express such a string:
anything, then dash and some digits. Empty input should be ok too, if possible.

so:

```
[nothing] = valid
astring = valid
astring- = invalid
astring-1 = valid
astring-a = invalid
astring-a1 = invalid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^-]*(-[0-9]+)?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dN1uM5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple regex :

```
^*(-[0-9]+)?$
```